# Uploading recipe changes to chef server using Berkshelf

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, berkshelf

I'm in the process of customizing community cookbooks (cassandra and elasticsearch) for use in production. From trying to get to grips with Berkshelf I have found myself uploading changes to my wrapper cookbook recipes from within my ~/chef-repo/cookbooks/ by executing:

```
Berks upload -b ./Berksfile --no-ssl-verify --force
```

This gets past the fact that my chef server is not certified, and overcomes the "frozen" cookbooks.

I'm sure that there's a better way to upload simple changes to my chef-server, as it feels somewhat extreme to force a re-upload of the entire cookbook and all it's dependencies?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Berks upload -b ./Berksfile --no-ssl-verify --force <my cookbook name>`

That will upload just the one cookbook you want (ie, the one you changed)

Comment: Thanks, although this feels really cumbersome after say, adding a simple attribute override. Using the chef-repo pattern with a wrapper cookbook, I can upload changes using knife upload cookbook

Comment: well, the `-b ./Berksfile` should be optional, as that's the default location.  The force would also be unnecessary if you were versioning your cookbooks (which you should).  EVERY change should be a new version.

Comment: Ding. Thanks man, I wasn't grasping the change in workflow before - makes total sense.